# How do I read source files from a directory and create object files into another folder in a makefile?

Tags: makefile, freebsd, c89

I have the following source files:

```
% ls 
data_lexicon.c  data_lexicon.h  lex.l           makefile
```

And the following makefile:

```
% cat makefile
CC              = cc
CFLAGS          = -Wall -std=c89
LDFLAGS         = -ll
OBJFILES        = lex.o data_lexicon.o
TARGET          = lexical_analyzer_1

all:            $(TARGET) lex.c

lex.c:          lex.l data_lexicon.h
                lex -olex.c lex.l

$(TARGET):      $(OBJFILES)
                $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJFILES) $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
                rm -f $(OBJFILES) lex.c $(TARGET)
```

If I do `make all` I get:

```
% ls 
data_lexicon.c          data_lexicon.o          lex.l
lexical_analyzer_1      data_lexicon.h          lex.c
lex.o                   makefile
```

So far so good.

However, I would like to move the source files (data_lexicon.c, data_lexicon.h, lex.l) to a folder `src` and generate the intermediate files (data_lexicon.o lex.c, lex.o) into a `obj` folder.

I create both folders but I do not understand how the `makefile` file shall be configured.

I am using FreeBSD make, so the more portable the solution given the better.

Comment: You are mixing terms "directory" and "folder". On BSD/Unix/Linux, they are directories and not the Windows user term of folder which is not the same thing.

Comment: Just to say: if you restrict yourself to portable/standard make, then John Bollinger's answer below is exactly correct: the only portable way to create an implicit rule (POSIX suffix rules) cannot describe situations where the target lives in a separate directory from the controlling prerequisite.  You will have to write an explicit rule for every target.  Of course, various implementations of make have ways to avoid this but then you're not portable any longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I would like to move the source files (data_lexicon.c,
> data_lexicon.h, lex.l) to a folder src and generate the intermediate
> files (data_lexicon.o lex.c, lex.o) into a obj folder.

It never ceases to amaze me how people insist on making extra work for themselves.  You can certainly do what you describe, but it will require writing explicit rules for the object files.

First of all, however, you need to understand that `make` itself doesn't really know anything about directories. (Traditional `make` doesn't, anyway.  GNU `make` and perhaps others know a *little* about them.)  That is, it doesn't have any sense of varying directories against which it resolves file names.  Rather, every target name is resolved against `make`'s working directory.  If you want to refer to something in a subdirectory, then you must say so.  To begin with:

```
OBJFILES        = obj/lex.o obj/data_lexicon.o
```

Similar goes for target and prerequisite names in rules:

```
obj/lex.c:      src/lex.l src/data_lexicon.h
                lex -o$@ src/lex.l
```

That's also one reason to favor `make`'s automatic variables, such as the `$@` in the above rule representing the name of the target being built.

Your makefile presently relies on `make`'s built-in rule for building object files from corresponding C source files, but "corresponding" means target and prerequisite names are *identical*, including any path components, except for the suffixes (`.c` *vs* `.o`). You will no longer have that correspondence for `data_lexicon.o`, so you will need to write an explicit rule for it building it.  This part is left as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Regarding the objective of this, is to have a clear, well organised and separated source code in a folder (and not generate extrawork).

Comment: @M.E., I'm sure you didn't wake up one morning thinking "I wonder what I can do today to make more work for myself?"  But the fact remains, and it is the point of my opening remark, that that is among the main results of insisting on building outputs to a separate directory dedicated to that purpose.  The benefits do not justify the costs, in my opinion.  If it's not enough for you to just write a `clean` target, then I would recommend looking into using `make`'s VPATH feature to provide for out-of-source building.

Comment: I actually thought of a `clean` target with erases intermediate stuff after your answer, so yes, that suffices